Typst add non-breaking whitespace in code
I have a custom function that formats a URL with an icon.
I want the space between the label and the icon to be non-breaking.
For this I would use the ~ character, but this does not work in code.
For example
== Unsuccessful attempt

#let mylink(label, dest) = {
  link(dest)[#emph(underline(label + "~" + box("URL!")))]
}


#mylink("hello", "https://wikipedia.org") // FAILS as ~ is used as a character


== Without code

hello~#box("URL!") // works

#link("https://wikipedia.org")[hello~URL!] // works

#link("https://wikipedia.org")[#underline("hello~URL!")] // FAILS as ~ is used as a character




What happens if you use a literal non-breaking space?

Then I have a non-breaking space. It looks ok in this case, but when the label ("hello") gets too long, it might break between the word and the added text (URL!).

In code, you have access to the sym.space.nobreak symbol:
#link("https://wikipedia.org")[#underline("hello" + sym.space.nobreak + "URL!")]


If you find yourself needing nonbreaking spaces in code often, you can define your own shorthand function with a show rule:
#let escape-nobreak(body) = {
  // Or use whatever other shorthand you want
  show "&nbsp;": sym.space.nobreak
  body
}

#escape-nobreak[
  Some other text...

  
  // Will have the same appearance as the screenshot above
  #link("https://wikipedia.org")[#underline("hello&nbsp;URL!")]
]


While the other answer does show one absolutely fine way of achieving what's needed, I'd like to show another way that, at least to me, seems a little bit prettier (since it's a bit shorter than typing sym.space.nobreak).
We can use function calling directly with a context block (square brackets) instead of code (parentheses):
#let mylink1(label, dest) = {
  link(dest)[#emph(underline(label + "~" + box("URL!")))]
} //                        ^-------------------------^
//                           Instead calling with parenthesis

#let mylink2(label, dest) = {
  link(dest)[#emph(underline[#label~#box("URL!")])]
} //                        ^-------------------^
//                           Let's call `underline` using brackets

== Unsuccessful attempt

#mylink1("hello", "https://wikipedia.org") // FAILS as ~ is used as a character

== Works now

#mylink2("hello", "https://wikipedia.org") // WORKS by using text mode


Of course in this case, we have to precede variables and functions with a pound sign, since we are in text mode.
By the way, looking closer at the call to link function, it takes two positional arguments: link(dest, body). So even your original code already makes use of calling the function with content.
#let mylink3(label, dest) = {
  link(dest, [#emph(underline[#label~#box("URL!")])])
} //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//           This content contains only one call to emph,
//           so we can shorten it further

#let mylink4(label, dest) = {
  link(dest, emph(underline[#label~#box("URL!")]))
}

#mylink3("hello from mylink3", "https://wikipedia.org")

#mylink4("hello from mylink3", "https://wikipedia.org")

And all of these versions of mylink function produce the same output: 

